# Encrypt URL parameters between two ASP.NET Core 6 MVC apps using ASP.NET Core Data Protection

Tags: encryption, asp.net-core-mvc, urlencode, asp.net-core-6.0, data-protection

I'm trying to find the best way of encrypting some parameters of a URL from `webapp1` which redirects to `webapp2`, and I've come across [ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which seemed pretty easy to use on multiple apps because is built in ASP.NET Core.

I'm getting this error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The payload was invalid. For more information go to [http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning'](http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning%27)

My guess is because even if I use `PersistKeysToFileSystem` to save the key to a common location on server and use same `purpose` string on both apps, `Purposes` is an array of strings and the framework add another `purpose` (which is the path to my app), next to my defined purpose.

So when the `weapp2` tries to decrypt the payload it will use my defined purpose and another automatically generated purpose which is different from the one generated by `webapp1`

My implementation below:

Webapp1 `Program.cs`:

```
    builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("path_on_server/to/save/keys"))
```

Webapp1 `HomeController.cs`:

```
private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

public HomeController(IDataProtectionProvider provider) 
{
    _protector = provider.CreateProtector("X_CustomPurpose")
    //--> Purposes[0]="local/path/to/my/web/app1"
    // Purposes[1] = "X_CustomPurpose"
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var retUrl = "https://webapp1&appId=15";
    return Redirect("https://webapp2?returnUrl="+_protector.Protect(retUrl)); // this generates a link like: `https://webapp2?returnUrl=axcasdascafacXXssaxaxasefsd` 
}
```

Webapp2 `Program.cs`:

```
    builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("path_on_server/to/save/keys"))
```

Webapp2 `HomeController.cs`:

```
private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

public HomeController(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
{
    _protector = provider.CreateProtector("X_CustomPurpose")
    //--> Purposes[0]="local/path/to/my/web/app2"
    // Purposes[1] = "X_CustomPurpose"
}

public IActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
{
    var payload = _protector.Unprotect(returnUrl); // -> here I get the error 
}
```

I tend to believe that this approach simply won't work because it wasn't intended to work like this. Can you point me to a 2023 approach of safely encoding a URL parameter in one app and decode it in another app?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `Data Protection` is meant to protect data on the machine, not over the wire. That's the job of HTTPS.  URLs like `https://webapp2?returnUrl=` are typically used in authentication. That's what standards like OpenID Connect are for, which is [already supported by ASP.NET Core Identity](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos You've guessed well, I'm trying to implement kind of a custom authentication. `WebbApp2` will be a authentication app which will generate a `jwt` token and `WebApp1` will be a client which will redirect to `2` if user is not authenticated.

Comment: I have a complicated infrastructure and I don't want Identity or oAuth

Comment: JWT is a standard, typically used along with OpenID Connect. It's already supported by ASP.NET Core. You don't need to write your own code to protect the token.

Comment: I want to encrypt the url that redirects tot token generator app --> `https://webapp2?returnUrl=axcasdascafacXXssaxaxasefsd`

Comment: Rolling your own makes things far more complicated. JWT Bearer is already supported through the  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer) package and there are [built in tools to test it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/jwt-authn?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows).

Comment: [MFA is also supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-7.0). It's not *your* application that needs to talk or redirect to a TOTP service though, unless you're trying something weird. It's the end user that needs a TOTP generator to create a key that your application will validate

Comment: Are you trying to skip the TOTP step in authentication, by sending the generated token to the authentication provider?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking...The jwt generator app (webapp2) will return a token back to  `returnUrl=` value to use it for validate the authentication